# Is there a function to find all lower case letters in a character vector?

Tags: r, case, lowercase

I just wrote one, but I was wondering if one already exists in R.

Here's the function BTW (suggestions for improvement are welcome):

```
set.seed(50)
x <- sample(c(letters, LETTERS), 7)

is.lower <- function(x)
{
    unlist(sapply(x, function(x2) {x2 %in% letters}))
}

is.lower(x)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`grepl("[a-z]",x)` for example?

```
> grepl("[a-z]",x)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

And why make it difficult?

```
> x %in% letters
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

No need to make your own function.

Comment: Hi Joris. I'm blushing from reading you're second solution. I am obviously very tired - time to go to sleep...  Thank you for the first solution, I didn't think about it.

Comment: @Tal : no need to blush, I've made almost exactly the same mistake a while ago. Some sleep might help though I guess ;-)

Comment: Here's a function that might help you out once in a while: 
TalGalili <- function(x) Sys.sleep(28800)

Answer (score 3):

Another approach with the values instead of a logical index as the result, would be to name the letters as themselves and use "["with x as the index:

```
 names(letters) <- letters
 letters[x]
#<NA>    w    k <NA>    y    c <NA> 
#  NA  "w"  "k"   NA  "y"  "c"   NA
```